# Connection error using Flutter, Node.js and Socket,.io

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

I'm trying to create a multiplayer TicTacToe with Flutter and Node.js using Socket.io.
Here the code:
**Flutter**

```
late io.Socket socket;
  final String url = 'http://localhost:5000';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    socket = io.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': true,
    });

    socket.connect();

    socket.onConnect((_) {
      debugPrint('Client connected');
    });

    socket.onError((data) => debugPrint('Error: $data'));
  }
```

**Node.js**

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; //port for https

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log('Client connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });

});

httpServer.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

When the Server run and Client try to connect i get this error:
*I/flutter ( 6060): Error: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 34102*

I tried to change PORT but nothing happened. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: use ip address instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the environment you're running your app `localhost:port` might not work.
If you're using an emulator each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router or firewall service that isolates it from your development machine network interfaces. An emulated device can't detect your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. It detects only that it is connected through ethernet to a router or firewall.

Localhost `127.0.0.1` refers to the emulated device loopback interface. Use `10.0.2.2` which is a special alias to your host loopback interface (127.0.0.1 on your development machine).

If you're using a real device make sure you're on the same network.

Or you can use 192.168.xxx.xxx IP address of the node server on your local network.

Comment: Now it works, thanks :)